# Approximate binomial dist in sql

Tags: normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function, sql

What is the best way of approximating a binomial distribution, given I have the following functions available:

- `normal_cdf`
- `beta_cdf`

see here for full list. [presto-docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.217/functions/math.html)

Is there any other good way to approximate a binomial distribution, given I am limited to sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use normal approximation, $\mathcal{B}(n, p)$ [can be approximated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with $\mathcal{N}(np, np(1-p))$. So you can use normal CDF to approximate binomial CDF.

Binomial probability mass function is ${n \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$. You can easily compute the latter part, the problem is the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). Recall that ${ n\choose k} = \frac{ n! }{ k! (n - k)! }$, so you can use [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) of the factorials to approximate it. That said, you probably want to go with normal approximation rather than bothering with this in SQL.

Moreover, if I remember correctly, [you can define custom functions for Presto as plugins](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.217/develop/functions.html), this sounds much better than doing it in SQL.